# Program will calculate most provided values except for some

Tags: c, loops, if-statement, while-loop, cs50

This is a simple currency change calculator in C for a course I'm taking (CS50).

It works pretty well, until you submit the values `0.15`, `4.2` and `4.3` (those are the ones I caught so far), the program freezes, doesn't output any results. I have to `CTRL + C` to force quit.

If I try another number, say `0.41` I get the correct answer.

Why is this happening?

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {

    printf("How much change do you owe: ");

    float amount;

    // (;;) represents an infinite loop
    for (;;)
    {
        amount = GetFloat();

        // if user's input is negative, the script will break and prompt the user to enter a positive value.
        if (amount >= 0) { 
            break;
        }

        printf("Please provide a positive value: ");
    }

    float cents = 100.0 * amount;
    float quarter = 0;
    float dime = 0;
    float nickel = 0;
    float penny = 0;


    // I used the shortcut to represent (cents = cents + 25.0)
    while (cents > 0) {
        if (cents >= 25.0) {
            cents -= 25.0;
            quarter += 1;
        } else if (cents >= 10.0) {
            cents -= 10.0;
            dime += 1;
        } else if (cents >= 5.0) {
            cents -= 5.0;
            nickel += 1;
        } else if (cents >= 1.0) {
            cents -= 1.0;
            penny += 1;
        }
    }

    float coins = quarter + dime + nickel + penny;

    printf("%f\n", coins);
}
```

Comment: Floating-point numbers are not reals, they have limited precision. In particular, they may not be able to precisely represent `0.1`. Thus, `cents` may end up being `0 < cents < 1`, in which case the while-loop doesn't decrement `cents`, making the loop non-terminating.

Comment: cs50.h? smells like homework. and btw, this is not a script.

Comment: deleted my answer, not having read @EOF comment properly ... it's already there.

Comment: Have you covered arrays yet (or structures)?  If so, there are better ways to organize this code.  If not, you can continue as you are for a week or two.

Comment: float values always have decimal point and a trailing 'f'.   Not all values can be 'exactly' defined in a float.  Suggest: write your float literals as #.##f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably represent items that have a discrete value as integers and not floating point numbers. If cents is a non integer number (10.1 for example), that loop will never end.

I tried this out and entering 0.15 assigned cents to 15.0000010, due to floating point error.

Comment: I changed my variables to `int` except `amount` but other values started to break, here is the output of `check50` `:( input of 0.41 yields output of 4
   \ expected output, but not "3\n"`

Comment: 25+10+5+1 = 41. I'm not sure why 4 isn't valid here. Did you also fix the printf format string?

Comment: I fixed it! I had to edit `int cents = roundf(amount * 100.0);` and a quick `check50` gave all green, good to go.

Comment: @Halnex: That might have worked by chance for few cases. However, **do not use floating point for currency**. You asked for help, you get help and you should listen - or at least verify - what you get as answer and/or comment.

Comment: @Olaf yes, I got it now. I should've only used `float` for the `amount` which is a user input. This is the first assignment from the course so it's still in the beginning and I should note that this isn't a `Programming Course` rather it is an introduction to Computer Science in general.

Comment: @Halnex: Not even that! Just lean back and think what a sentence like "I tried this out and entering 0.15 assigned cents to 15.0000010 ..." implies. Before using floating point values, everyone should make comfortable with the [pitfalls](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) of this format.

Comment: @Halnex: Note: A CS course should even more concentrate on correct data types and the basics. That is actually the basis for programming.

Answer (score -3):

What is `#include <cs50.h>`? and also

Your logic makes no sense. Is this a c programming course?
These are your values for the amount

```
float cents = 100.0 * amount;
float quarter = 0;
float dime = 0;
float nickel = 0;
float penny = 0;
```

And your giving them a value of zero, and when sum up the values its equal to 0. That's why lol, your telling the machine to print 0 and its doing that. These are your conditions why do you need a loop fix your conditions. you can use a case switch to simplify this or just fix your conditions.

```
        while (cents > 0) {
    if (cents >= 25.0) {
        cents -= 25.0;
        quarter += 1;
    } else if (cents >= 10.0) {
        cents -= 10.0;
        dime += 1;
    } else if (cents >= 5.0) {
        cents -= 5.0;
        nickel += 1;
    } else if (cents >= 1.0) {
        cents -= 1.0;
        penny += 1;
    }
}
```

Give amount a value at the top because value can be any number set the value to =0 and throw in a printf after the scanf to display the value the user entered again.

Comment: cs50.h is probably a library his university course gave him

Comment: If you intended to imply that `<cs50.h>` is erroneous, then perhaps it might be wise to explain that, following your question "What is `#include <cs50.h>`?" That aside, if you would work on your grammar then I can see similar answers being considered useful... and I'm going to vote not to delete this.